# RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I got an error with `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `RecyclerView` when I press back button. This is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public List<Article> articleList;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        initData();
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(articleList, MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

      private void initData() {
        articleList = new ArrayList<>();
        queryArticle();
    }

      public void saveArticle(String title, String desc) {
        //ab is a instance for class Article_Bmob
        ab.setTitle(title);
        ab.setDesc(desc);

        ab.save(new SaveListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void done(String s, BmobException e) {

                if(e == null) {
                } else {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

     }
}
```

WriteArticle.java (Error File)

```
public class WriteArticle extends AppCompatActivity {
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    private String art_title, art_desc;
    private EditText edt_title, edt_desc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.write_article);

        edt_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.w_art_title);
        edt_desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.w_art_desc);
        Button btn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_article);

        mainActivity = new MainActivity();

        btn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                art_title = edt_title.getText().toString();
                art_desc = edt_desc.getText().toString();

                if (art_title.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "R.String.xxx", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                } else if (art_desc.isEmpty()) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "R.String.xxx", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                } else {
                    mainActivity.saveArticle(art_title, art_desc);
                    mainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

And the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'void com.myapplication.RecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
at com.myapplication.WriteArticle$1.onClick(WriteArticle.java:52)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't simply create an Activity by calling its Constructor as you do `mainActivity = new MainActivity();` here

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `mainActivity = new MainActivity();` ? Do you want to open the activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: Basically, don't make an instance of an Activity that you don't need. You can't just pass around data like this. Alternatively, maybe check this post.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: Other options include having the Write activity store things in a SQLite database that you read in the other Activity to a RecyclerView

Answer (score 3):

In your MainActivity

```
public static MainActivity mactivity;
public static MainActivity getinstance(){
    return mactivity;
}
```

In your WriteArticle activity

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
```

And use it as

```
mainActivity.getinstance.saveArticle(art_title, art_desc);
mainActivity.getinstance.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: This might work, but definitely isn't recommended. The Activity could be killed by the OS, so the exception will still occur

Comment: And that'll freeze the app for half a second. Why does that help?

Comment: There is no need for it. But you said that the activity could be killed by OS. You can alternatively pack data in intent and receive it before setting adapter.

Comment: Wait. What is the purpose of notifyDataSetChanged when there is no data in adapter? Post your full code including saveArticle and whole MainActivity.

Comment: Who are you asking? The saveArticle method is attempting to put data in the adapter

Comment: Yes, the saveArticle is putting data in the adapter

Comment: Now I got a similarly error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.myapplication.MainActivity.saveArticle(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` Did you mean that `return mactivity = new MainActivity();` ?